# Copiar y pegar en VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy teniendo dificultades con Visual Basic para excel. Recientemente estuve creando una plantilla de cotizacion para mi trabajo, esta automatizada para que, mediante una lista de materiales puedas verificar cual de ellos deseas introducir en la planilla. Debido a recientes cambios tuve que actualizar esta planilla, dando la opcion al usuario de agregar un nuevo item a este listado ya existente. Para eso, esta nueva funcion deberia introducir en cada uno de las hojas (Que realizan diferentes cambios en los precios) la misma formula que su antecesor
Es decir:
Si en al Celda A2 tengo "x" producto al cual lo multiplico por la cantidad que deseo en la celda B2 (`B2*A2`) y en la celda C2 le agrego impuestos (es decir (`(A2*21%)*B2`). Mi funcion deberia copiar la fila y pegarla debajo, realizando los cambios correspondientes, es decir, remplazar todos los numeros por un 3: A3, B3 (`B3*A3`), (`C3(A3*21%)*B3`). Tal y como lo hace excel al arrastrar la formula en diferentes celdas o cuando se desea realizar una secuencia numerica donde arrastramos las primeras dos celdas para que autocomplete el resto.

De momento estuve realizando este cambio de forma manual ya que me copia la formula tal cual esta, sin realizar el cambio que deseo. Les dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando asi como el excel para lo mas curiosos.

Espero haberme explicado con claridad. Cualquier consulta estoy a disposicion

`Sheets("PRORRATEO").Range("V47").Copy: Sheets("PRORRATEO").Range("V48").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Tambien he intentado con
`Sheets("PRORRATEO").Range("V47").Copy: Sheets("PRORRATEO").Range("V48").Paste`
Pero me pide depurar.

Link del Excel: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUxd7Ze6AB25MVfyxlY9dSlWUeQBTDCH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: en vez de `PasteAll` prueba con `xlPasteFormulas`. Mira también la propiedad `Autofill`

Comment: Probe remplazando `PasteAll` con `xlPasteFormlas` pero no obtuve el resultado que queria. Tambien intente con la propiedad que me mencionas, pero excel no me permite utilizarla no se bien a que se deba `Sheets("PRORRATEO").Range("C35:C47").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("PRORRATEO").Range("C47:C49"), Type:=xlFillCopy`

Gracias por el aporte

Comment: Si escribiste `xlPasteFormlas` no está bien escrito. Mira, usa el grabador de macros. Copia normal y luego cuando vayas a pegar, utiliza la opcion **Pegar fórmula**. Es justo lo que estás buscando

Comment: Excelente respuesta, no entiendo como no se me ocurrio antes. Muchisimas gracias, aun no lo pruebo, cuando pueda lo intentare y aviso. Pero estoy seguro de con el grabador de macros funcionara. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hoy realice la prueba correspondiente con el ejemplo que @Esei me facilito. Utilice grabar un macro copiando y pegando una formula random para que me devuelva la funcion que requeria; tuve que realizar una pequeña modificacion para que esta funcione. 
Dejo la funcion que use:
```Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("X51").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("X52").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Hoja1").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False```

Especial agradecimiento a @Esei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoy realice la prueba correspondiente con el ejemplo que @Esei me facilito. Utilice grabar un macro copiando y pegando una formula random para que me devuelva la funcion que requeria; tuve que realizar una pequeña modificacion para que esta funcione.
Dejo la funcion que use:

````
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("X51").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("X52").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Hoja1").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False```

Especial agradecimiento a @Esei.
````